# Scrape URL loop with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, url, beautifulsoup

I want to scrap information on different pages of the same site, societe.com and I have several questions.

first of all here is the code that I managed to do, I am a bit of a novice I admit it

I only put 2 URLs to see if the loop worked and some information, I can add some when everything works

```
urls = ["https://www.societe.com/societe/decathlon-france-500569405.html","https://www.societe.com/societe/go-sport-312193899.html"]
for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    numrcs = soup.find("td", class_="numdisplay")
    nomcommercial = soup.find("td", class_="break-word")
    print(nomcommercial.text)
    print(numrcs.text.strip())
    numsiret = soup.select('div[id^=siret_number]')
    for div in numsiret:
        print(div.text.strip())
    formejuri = soup.select('div[id^=catjur-histo-description]')
    for div in formejuri:
        print(div.text.strip())
    infosend = {
        'numrcs': numrcs,
        'nomcommercial':nomcommercial,
        'numsiret':numsiret,
        'formejuri':formejuri
    }
    tableau.append(infosend)
print(tableau)

my_infos = ['Numéro RCS',  'Numéro Siret ','Forme Juridique']

my_columns = [
    np.tile(np.array(my_infos), len(nomcommercial))
]

df = pd.DataFrame( tableau,index=nomcommercial, columns=my_columns)
df
```

When I run the loop I have the right information coming out, like for example

```
DECATHLON FRANCE
Lille Metropole B 500569405
50056940503239
SASU Société par actions simplifiée à associé unique
```

but I would like to put all this information in a table but I can't really, only the last company appears and the data makes no sense I tried to follow a tutorial without success.

if you can help me i would be really happy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get data about the companies you can use next example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


urls = [
    "https://www.societe.com/societe/decathlon-france-500569405.html",
    "https://www.societe.com/societe/go-sport-312193899.html",
]

headers = {
    "User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36"
}

data = []
for url in urls:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser"
    )
    title = soup.select_one("#identite_deno").get_text(strip=True)
    rcs = soup.select_one('td:-soup-contains("Numéro RCS") + td').get_text(
        strip=True
    )
    siret_number = soup.select_one("#siret_number").get_text(strip=True)
    form = soup.select_one("#catjur-histo-description").get_text(strip=True)

    data.append([title, url, rcs, siret_number, form])


df = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    columns=["Title", "URL", "Numéro RCS", "Numéro Siret", "Forme Juridique"],
)
print(df.to_markdown())
```

Prints:

|  | Title | URL | Numéro RCS | Numéro Siret | Forme Juridique |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | DECATHLON FRANCE (DECATHLON DIRECTION GENERALE FRANCE) | https://www.societe.com/societe/decathlon-france-500569405.html | Lille Metropole B 500569405 | 50056940503239 | SASU Société par actions simplifiée à associé unique |
| 1 | GO SPORT | https://www.societe.com/societe/go-sport-312193899.html | Grenoble B 312193899 | 31219389900191 | Société par actions simplifiée |